# What's a solid but basic search algorithm for php?

Tags: php, algorithm, search

I am working on a project that involves searching for videos, these videos are tagged similar to how questions are tagged on stack overflow.  I was wondering if anyone knows of a good 'tag-based' search algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using a database indexed on tags?

Comment: Bit difficult to answer without more details. Do you want searches to have to match tags exactly? If so, it's a very simple search "algorithm" (look up videos with a particular tag); and a more complex UI problem (help the user find exact matches). If not, it's a slightly more complex search problem (find similar tags, then find videos on those tags). I think you'll need to clarify how you want it to behave before anyone can help.

Comment: I have a separate tags table that relates videos to tags, videos may contain multiple tags or multi-word tags

Comment: Dominic, good point..  I guess the exact match part is easy, it's what to do if no 'exact matches' are found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what operations (write ? read ? both ?) you plan to use the most, there are different approaches.

Here an interesting reading: [Tags: Database schemas](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html) comparing some well-known website tags schema.

Answer (score 0):

How about searching tags, then titles, then descriptions, only widening the search from one method to the next if no results are found using the current method?

As an aside; if you want to return non-exact matches to your users, make sure they aren't so non-exact that they start becoming irrelevant! :)